# Binding to an element in the ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf

How do you make binding to a collection item in this case?

```
//Both collections have OnPropertyChanged("");
public ObservableCollection<Grid> ConnectorsGrids { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<double> Connectors { get; set; }

//Coordinates collection
Connectors = new ObservableCollection<double>() { 10 , A - 20 };

ConnectorsGrids = new ObservableCollection<Grid>();

foreach (var e in Connectors)
{
    ConnectorsGrids.Add(DrawConnector(new Thickness(e * YB1, 0, 0, 0)));
}
```

`YB1` is the coefficient for the element's size. It is variable depending on the size of the screen

`YB1` is not in any collection. Is a parameter in the class

`DrawConnector()` takes the margin as a parameter

I would like the margin to change depending on the size of the screen

At the moment, it calculates the output value and afterwards when changing the size of the screen, the changes remain

Comment: You need to listen to the event `SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged` to know when the screen size is changed and then re-compute `YB1` and possibly re-create `ConnectorGrid` items.

Comment: why do you have an observable collection of <Grid> that's a little unusual would you please elaborate what you are trying to achieve on a bigger scale? where are you binding your observableCollection

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

xaml:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="PART_ItemsControl"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Connectors}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={local:ToGridConverter}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Converter:

```
sealed class ToGridConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is double)
    {
       double e = (double)value;
       return DrawConnector(new Thickness(e * YB1, 0, 0, 0));
    }            
    return Binding.DoNothing;
}
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private ToGridConverter _converter;
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (_converter == null)
    {
        _converter = new ToGridConverter ();
    }
    return _converter;
}}
```